# React Native: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: react-native

I've tried gradlew clean and every other solution available here and on GitHub but the error doesn't match and solution doesn't work

> Error on cmd After running `react-native run-android`

```
 > Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
    D8: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzda


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\0.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\1.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\27.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\31.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\43.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\New folder\App\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 39s
82 actionable tasks: 78 executed, 4 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I have tried all the solutions but none seems to work. Please Help

> react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
>   react-native: 0.53.0

**build.gradle file:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

ext {
  compileSdkVersion = 26
  targetSdkVersion = 26
  buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
  supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
  googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
  oreoEXPERIMENTAL = "yes"
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cherishx_vendors"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

---

### Edit

After adding `multidexEnabled = true` to **android/app/build.gradle file**
the following error pops up :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
68 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 67 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

This error is not answered anywhere so I included this as an update to this question.

Comment: Please add your `android/app/build.gradle`, assuming you ejected.

Comment: Added @JohannaLarsson

Comment: can you share how you solve it I'm faced the same

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Got same error a couple of days back, seems you've got to enable multidex to true and delete the build folder.

Go to `android/app/build.gradle` and add the line `multiDexEnabled true` and set minSdkVersion to 21 inside `defaultConfig` like this

```java
...
android{
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
...
```

You can check this thread out on react-native

https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android/issues/32

Comment: enable this where? 
I've tried removing and ejecting /android, it doesn't work (the solutions on the github)

Comment: In your module level build.gradle file. Something like this:
`android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}`

Comment: What version of android are you running on?

You might need to add in your android/build.gradle file
`dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}`
if you're running below os of sdk less than 20

Comment: It is version 23+

Comment: Please add your `android/app/build.gradle` file to your question

Comment: Added The following

Comment: Change your `minSdkVersion to 21` and the next line add, `multiDexEnabled true` i.e. in your android/app/build.gradle file
read more about this on https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Comment: @SanchitBhatnagar as pointed out, if your minSdkVersion is lower than 21 you need to add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` to your dependencies. Or increase minSdkVersion to 21 or higher.

Comment: Done All that and now a new error popped up ^ 
Mentioned it in the 'Edit'

Comment: This solution worked for me, followed the docs here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle

Comment: Glad it could be of help @Cyrois

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea

Comment: Make sure to give a hints about the answer and provide the link if some one want to read more about it

Comment: It worked for me on react-native-cli without changing minSdkVersion, just added `multiDexEnabled true` line and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

I have fixed by enabling the multiDex in the /android/app/build.gradle file.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    .......
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ......
}
```

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea

Comment: This is correct recommended answer for react native

Answer (score 15):

Open the **/android/app/build.gradle** file.

Under dependencies we need to add the module, and then enable it within defaultConfig

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    // ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: great. I can confirm this works with `"react-native": "0.62.2"`. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I solve issue by enabling

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    // ...
}
```

path : android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 5):

Add following to your `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
   ....
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I  confronted with this error

> Execution failed for task ':app:multiDexListDebug'.

but He wrote in the continuation of my error that

I installed async-storage from two address
and when I remove the second

errors have been fixed

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",

"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
```

Comment: my case it was the masked-view `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` and `@react-native-community/masked-view`

Answer (score 4):

This will fix it
cd android && ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 3):

you probably have to add the `multiDexEnabled true` property to your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true

    // (...) more properties
}
```

The console error gives you a hint to overcome this problem. They show you this very link: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

you can learn more about the problem there. But this was my solution here in 2020. Peace!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. So to make it 'clearer', I did these:

1. Update to sdk27 (compile and target). minSdk is at 21
2. Update related goodle-play base/services/maps to 15.0.1 (Depends on your project requirement)
3. Then: I add `multidexEnabled=true` in the same section as no (1) above
4. (Optional) - I had another issue where Gradle couldn't find the play-services version properly: I modified the project `build.gradle` to search the google maven first before the `jcenter()`

   ```
   maven {
       url 'https://maven.google.com/'
       name 'Google'
   }
   mavenLocal()
   jcenter()
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
At Path android/app/build.gradle

defaultConfig {
multiDexEnabled true //Add this line
}
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1344

Answer (score 1):

As an update to this answer (if people can't figure out why, especially one Mac)

use sudo! I was trying to figure out why gradlew commands were not running for ages, turns out - it didnt have permission!

Use:

`sudo ./gradlew [command]`

I'm so frustrated and happy at the same time.

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea

Answer (score 1):

In the file (`<your_project_folder>/android/app/build.gradle`), amend the code with the following lines:

```
android {
    ...
   packagingOptions {
       pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
   }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts/issues/80

Answer (score 1):

Just run

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

then

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to use latest dex version

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Comment: This is correct recommended answer for react native

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers given here but nothing worked as this issue is no more resolved just by using `multiDexEnabled true`.
We can get the updated solution from this [link](https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex). And don't forget to clean the project after this by using the command `cd android && ./gradlew clean`. As many of us still get the same error after implementing the solution. So it's a good practice to clean the project.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling Multidex at **/android/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        multiDexEnabled true //add this
    }
    // ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' //latest version
}
```

Extending MultiDexApplication at **android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java**

```
// ... all your other imports here
import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication; // add this import


// Your class definition needs `extends MultiDexApplication` like below
public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {
```

source: https://rnfirebase.io/enabling-multidex

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to your android/build.gradle file

```
    ext {
            googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.1"
            // ... rest of ext properties
        }
```

https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/wiki/Android-build-problems

Answer (score 0):

me too had this same error, and i was able to debug it using the command `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`(inside android folder) and for me it was because i had two libraries and both were having same package name, on changing package name of one resolved the issue

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59096566/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug-rea

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Go to Android Studio
2. Open your project file
3. Click on *Build*
4. Click on *Clean Project*
5. Build again with `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

remove "@react-native-community/async-storage" ----> package.json

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).