# Compile error while react-native-maps building

Tags: react-native

I'm new to `react-native` and I'm keeping getting an error while trying to build with `react-native-maps`.
Steps I made:

```
react-native init --version="0.57.4" <my_app_name>
cd <my_app_name>
react-native install react-native-geocoder
react-native install react-native-maps
react-native run-android
```

Error message:

```
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

Following instructions from @samitha-nanayakkara, I've reached this [issue](https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android/issues/32), I did try to delete the build directories each time and edit `android/app/build.gradle` like:

```
defaultConfig {
...
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

That give me the error message:

```
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

Also, trying Java 8 give me the same result:

```
defaultConfig {
...
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Adding `multiDexEnabled true` to android/app/build.gradle give me another error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239400/react-native-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithexternallib

Comment: Adding `multiDexEnabled true` to `android/app/build.gradle` give me another error message:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.`

Comment: I haven’t face that problem before and cannot tell you what is the reason. But dod you try this link? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/793

Comment: Thanks dude, adding `dependencies { implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0' }` to the `android/app/build.gradle` just before `android{...}` appears to solve the problem.