# Error React-native-screen StackViewCard.js

Tags: react-native

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-screens`

how to fix it ? i've been delete node_modules and npm i again but still meet this error react-native-screens

Comment: Does your package json have the dependency added

Comment: there is no react-native-screen package json, but when im npm i react-native-screen a new error is found about 'app:transformdexarchivewithexternallibsdexmergerfordebug'

Comment: Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239400/react-native-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformdexarchivewithexternallib